# Configuring auth - .Configure<JwtBearerOptions> vs .AddJwtBearer(Action<JwtBearerOptions> options)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

As per title, what's the difference between these two?

I can't find any docs that explain the difference between them and when is the right time to use either of them.

I have used both for my authentication with Azure AD, and both seem to work just fine. So what's the difference between these two?

```
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
    services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = configuration["AzureAd:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = configuration["AzureAd:Audience"],
        };
        options.Authority = configuration["AzureAd:Authority"];
    });

    // VERSUS

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = configuration[ConfigConstants.AuthorityConfig];
            options.Audience = configuration[ConfigConstants.ClientIdConfig];
        });
```

Comment: What version of ASP.NET Core are you using?

Comment: **In short**: `.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>()` by itself won't do anything useful because it doesn't register all of the service types needed for JWT handling, nor does it get you a `AuthenticationBuilder  object needed for further _required_ configuration: only the `AddJwtBearer()` method does that (though you are still free to (try to) manually register all of the necessary services by yourself..

Comment: _"I have used both for my authentication with Azure AD, and both seem to work just fine. So what's the difference between these two?"_ - I highly doubt that you were able to successfully use `Configure<JwtBearerOptions>()` **alone** and it still worked...

Comment: Must've configured something else wrong then. Or the auth was not working at all in the first place :)

Comment: Can you dig-up your old code and add it to your post? I'm curious what you hand.

Comment: Is it `.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi` that's doing that? Honestly, at this point I'm so confused with what each option is doing, whether if any of these overlap with each other.

Comment: Correct: yes, `.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi` calls `AddJwtBearer` by itself here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/101e9c241d637f9413629b881d1aae26f3496bc9/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web/WebApiExtensions/MicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L144